# MySQL slow query from intranet

Tags: mysql

This is a problem a friend of mine has.

He has a table `keyword` with only `9000` records. The `MySQL` server has a public ip and when I execute `SELECT id, word FROM keyword` from my machine(I access the `MySQL` server over the Internet), the query is very fast(200 milliseconds). No matter how many times I run it, it is very fast as it should be. So far so good.

Now he runs the same query from his machine in his intranet and accesses the `MySQL` server again with the public ip. The query sometimes takes as much as `40` seconds and it is logged as a slow query in the `MySQL` server log. He tried also from another machine in his intranet and again it takes sometimes as much as `40` seconds.

How is this possible? If it is a network problem only in his intranet, then why `MySQL` logs it as a slow query? AFAIK, `MySQL` query time in the slow query log doesn't include network transfer?

How to troubleshoot this problem? I am really frustrated.

Greetings,

Petar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to see the difference:

```
SET profiling = 1;
SELECT id, word FROM keyword;
```

and maybe add:

```
SHOW PROFILES;
```

More information in the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profile.html

Comment: The problem mysteriously disappeared. Anyway thanks for the suggestion. I will use it when needed.